# ¿Como puedo hacer un count agrupando por un parametro?

Tags: mysql, mysqlprocedure, mysql-procedimiento

Tengo que hacer un ejercicio con un procedimiento para obtener el número de grupos que se pueden hacer a partir de cualquiera de los atributos que forman parte de la clave primaria.

El nombre de dicha clave la pasamos como parámetro, que puede ser Nombre_personaje o Nombre_Gadget.

El caso es que consigo que funcione usando el nombre de la clave directamente pero no cuando lo hago usando el parametro:

Codigo:

```
DELIMITER &&
CREATE procedure actividad3(in atributo varchar(40)) 
BEGIN

    SELECT Cantidad,
       COUNT(*)
       FROM (SELECT atributo, 
                    COUNT(*) as Cantidad
                    FROM Desbloquea
                    GROUP BY atributo
                    
       ) as c
       GROUP BY Cantidad
       having COUNT(atributo);

END; &&
DELIMITER ;
```

Creo que falla algo con el having.

El resultado debería ser este:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que corresponde a las agrupaciones de esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero haciendolo con el parametro solo consigo esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: "Creo que falla algo con el HAVING": ¿Entendés [el funcionamiento](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/having.php) de `HAVING`?

Comment: La verdad que no entiendo que es lo que necesitas hacer. Tu SP no tiene sentido. ¿Podrías [edit] tu pregunta y agregar un ejemplo que lo que tenes y lo que quisieras obtener? Es decir, un [mre]

Comment: Si, claro, en un momento lo cambio

Comment: La verdad es que no termino de entender el funcionamiento de having.

Comment: Y leiste la documentacion sobre having? having, es el where para el group by... es lo que usa para filtrar que grupos mostrar dentro del group by.. aca no tiene sentido.. y si queres pasar un campo como variable, entonces vas a tener que hacer un query dinamico, porque si no, cualquier db va a tomar el parametro como nombre de campo...

Comment: @gbianchi, lo del having se supone, según la profesora, que tengo que usarlo de algún modo para que pueda funcionarme. Y tiene que ser usando los parametros. No sé que es lo del query dinámico.

Comment: @Marcos ya está cambiado :)

Comment: Entonces vas a tener que preguntarle a tu profesora que quiere. El having, en lo que estas mostrando aca, no tiene nada que ver... el Having es el filtro por el cual te quedas con un grupo o no...

Comment: @gbianchi entonces no tiene snetido usar having ya que queremos coger todo.

Comment: y no.. no tendria sentido... luego, debes comparar la variable que recibes y hacer un query u otro segun la variable que recibis. Yo por lo menos desconozco si mysql permite escribir columnas dinamicas (que no sabes cuales son) basadas en una variable que recibir por parametro...

Comment: Por favor, pon la estructura de tu tabla y un ejemplo del campo por el que quieres hacer los agrupamientos. Lo de 'a partir de cualquiera de los atributos que forman parte de la clave primaria' no lo deja claro

Comment: @VFG es a partir de Nombre_personaje o Nombre_Gadget